# DocuSign REST- Envelop sent does not show under DocuSign Status related list

Tags: rest, salesforce

I'm writing a Salesforce-DocuSign integration using REST and need my envelope to be associated with a custom object.
Could somebody show me how to relate the envelope to other objects?
Do we have to use the below resource? https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeCustomFields/
Actually I tried to create envelope with following json, which does have custom fields.  I am not sure about name property in textCustomFields, right now I have a value which corresponds to the envelop custom field that I created in DocuSign console. Should it be "EnevelopeExternalSourceId'? or 'DSFSSourceObjectId'?
The value that I passed in the request json is not populated. 
Can someone point me in right direction?
DocuSign logs show the following:
Attempting search for object ID, Search Value: Created
Search query: find {Created} in all fields returning My_Custom_Object__c(id)
Object not found.

Anyone done this for REST? I found some SOAP examples, not a single rest example.

```
   {
        "textCustomFields": [{
            "value": "a54c00000000iwpAAA",
            "show": "true",
            "required": "true",
            "name": "GCApplicationID",
            "fieldId": null
        }],
        "status": "created",
        "recipients": {
            "signers": [{
                "tabs": {
                    "signHereTabs": [{
                        "yPosition": null,
                        "xPosition": null,
                        "width": "100",
                        "TabLabel": null,
                        "tabid": null,
                        "ScaleValue": null,
                        "required": "TRUE",
                        "RecipientId": "1",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "optional": "false",
                        "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                        "anchorString": "SIGNHERE",
                        "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true"
                    }],
                    "dateSignedTabs": [{
                        "width": "100",
                        "TabLabel": null,
                        "tabid": null,
                        "ScaleValue": null,
                        "required": "TRUE",
                        "RecipientId": "1",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "DocumentId": "1",
                        "anchorYoffset": null,
                        "anchorXOffset": null,
                        "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                        "anchorString": "DATESIGNED",
                        "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true"
                    }]
                },
                "routingOrder": null,
                "rolename": null,
                "recipientId": "1",
                "name": "Some Name",
                "email": "yuiuyiuiy@gyuiua.com",
                "clientUserId": null
            }, {
                "tabs": {
                    "signHereTabs": [{
                        "yPosition": null,
                        "xPosition": null,
                        "width": "100",
                        "TabLabel": null,
                        "tabid": null,
                        "ScaleValue": null,
                        "required": "TRUE",
                        "RecipientId": "1",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "optional": "false",
                        "Name": null,
                        "fontSize": "Size12",
                        "font": "Calibri",
                        "DocumentId": "1",
                        "anchorYoffset": null,
                        "anchorXOffset": null,
                        "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                        "anchorString": "GUARANTOR2",
                        "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true"
                    }],
                    "initialHereTabs": [{
                        "yPosition": null,
                        "xPosition": null,
                        "width": "100",
                        "TabLabel": null,
                        "tabid": null,
                        "ScaleValue": null,
                        "required": "TRUE",
                        "RequireAll": "FALSE",
                        "RecipientId": "1",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "optional": "false",
                        "Name": null,
                        "fontSize": "Size12",
                        "font": "Calibri",
                        "documentId": "1",
                        "anchorYoffset": null,
                        "anchorXOffset": null,
                        "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                        "anchorString": "Guarantor INITIALHERE",
                        "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true"
                    }],
                    "dateSignedTabs": [{
                        "yPosition": null,
                        "xPosition": null,
                        "width": "100",
                        "TabLabel": null,
                        "tabid": null,
                        "ScaleValue": null,
                        "required": "TRUE",
                        "RecipientId": "1",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "Name": null,
                        "fontSize": "Size12",
                        "font": "Calibri",
                        "DocumentId": "1",
                        "anchorYoffset": null,
                        "anchorXOffset": null,
                        "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                        "anchorString": "G2DATE",
                        "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "true"
                    }]
                },
                "routingOrder": null,
                "rolename": null,
                "recipientId": "2",
                "name": "Joseph  Testcase",
                "email": "kykyky@nowhere.com",
                "clientUserId": null
            }],
            "carbonCopies": []
        },
        "messagelock": "false",
        "emailsubject": "DocuSign:1163778-01 - M Company - Company",
        "emailblurb": "Please sign attached document(s)",
        "documents": [{
            "name": "1163778-01 - Standard Doc Package-Dealer.docx",
            "documentid": "1",
            "documentBase64": null
        }]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. The name of the custom field I used is 'DSFSSourceObjectId', and no need to pass any value for this in your request JSON. Only thing you need is the correct mapping between your SaleForce custom object and this custom ID field (DocuSign field).

Comment: User @stohn asks: Can you please clarify what the body's JSON consists of, after the correct change?

Comment: @stohn, I was away for a while, If you still are looking for the JSON here is what it looks like. {
  "status": "created",
  "recipients": {
  "customFields": {
   "textCustomFields": [{
    "value": "salesforceId goes here",
    "show": "false",
    "required": "true",
    "name": "DSFSSourceObjectId",
    "fieldId": null
   }]
  }
 }